# How to get a panding amount and cancel amount by sql query

Tags: mysql, procedure

A master query gives all receipt including panding amount, total amount, discount amount, cancel amount and paid amount of 4 fees instalment installment 1, installment 2, installment 3, installment 4.
**Table structure**

[FeesTypeOf]
Id,name,schoolid
Data
1 | installment 1
2 | installment 2
3 | installment 3
4 | installment 4

[FeesOf]
Id,FeeTypeId, Amount,schoolid
1 | 1 | 15,000 | 1
2 | 2 | 15,000 | 1

[Receipt]
Id, Receipt no,feeid,ispaid,iscancel,studentid, discount,amountpaid.

1 | r1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2011 | 500 |7000

Expected data

Total amount 15000
7000 canceled
Panding amount 15000
(Due to cancel receipt)

I want total amount of each fees type , amount panding of each fees type ,discount of each fee, cancel amout will plus with panding amount,

Total amount 15000
7000 canceled
Panding amount 15000
(Due to cancel receipt)

I want total amount of each fees type , amount panding of each fees type ,discount of each fee, cancel amout will plus with panding amount